# Trying to understand why my stopwatch code is doing nothing (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, stopwatch

I am trying to write python code that will display a stopwatch in an entry box using tkinter.

My idea is to use a recursive function to add 1 to the box every second using time.sleep(1).

I am stumped - nothing happens when I press either button, and I get no error codes so I have no idea why it's not working.

The only time I get anything in the box is after pressing Stop, and it's always "00:00:00".

```
from tkinter import *
import time


root = Tk()
root.title("Stopwatch")

#box to display stopwatch
box = Entry(root, width = 20, borderwidth = 5)
box.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

#displays stopwatch in the box
def show_timer():
    global hrs, mins, secs, timer
    timer = str(hrs).zfill(2) + ":" + str(mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(secs).zfill(2)
    box.delete(0, END)
    box.insert(0, timer)

#check = 1 allows the stopwatch to run
def set_check(i):
    global check
    check = i
    return check

#actual function for stopwatch
def stopwatch():
    global check, hrs, mins, secs
    if check == 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        if int(secs) < 59:
            secs += 1
            return secs
        elif mins < 59:
            mins += 1
            secs = 0
            return mins, secs
        else:
            hrs += 1
            mins = 0
            secs = 0
            return hrs, mins, secs
        show_timer()
        stopwatch()
    else:
        show_timer()


def start():
    global hrs, mins, secs
    hrs, mins, secs = 0, 0, 0
    return hrs, mins, secs
    show_timer()
    set_check(1)
    stopwatch()

def stop():
    set_check(0)
    stopwatch()



start_button = Button(root, text = "Start", command = start)
stop_button = Button(root, text = "Stop", command = stop)

start_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
stop_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `return` leaves the current function call, so your `def start(...` does nothing. Read up on [Tutorial - 4.6. Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

- Calling `time.sleep()` from a callback function interrupts the `tkinter` event loop, making the GUI unresponsive.
- `from tkinter import *` is not recommended. To avoid namespace pollution use e.g. `import tkinter as tk`.
- You `return` (= exit the function) from `start` without doing anything.
- Your functions don't need `return` statements; you don't seem to be using the returned values.
- All the three branches of the inner `if`-statement in `stopwatch` call `return`, so `stopwatch` can never be called recursively. That is probably not what you intended.
- This is a good thing because a recursive call from a callback would also interrupt the event-loop.
- You only need to use `global` when you want to *modify* variables. So e.g. `show_timer` doesn't need `global`. (BTW, you can modify the *contents* of container types like `list` and `dict` *without* using `global`.)
- The names that you've indicated as `global` do not exist in the global context.

In general, event-driven programs do not run on a rigid schedule. You could use `root.after()` to make it execute a callback after a certain time, but there is no guarantee that this time is exact.

So that I would suggest is:

- Save the time that you start the stopwatch.
- Use an `after` callback that runs every second.
- In that callback, get the current time and substract the start time from it. Display the difference.
- Note that at the end of the `after` callback, you have to re-register it to keep it running. (unless the stop button was pressed.

In my tkinter programs, I like to keep all the state in a `types.SimpleNamespace` to make it clear that this is the program state.
Here is a working version with thise changes:

```
import time
import types
import tkinter as tk


def start():
    state.starttime = time.time()
    state.run = True
    display()
    root.after(1000, update)


def stop():
    state.run = False
    state.starttime = None
    box.delete(0, tk.END)


def update():
    if state.run:
        display()
        root.after(1000, update)


def display():
    difference = int(time.time() - state.starttime)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(difference, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    display = "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
    box.delete(0, tk.END)
    box.insert(0, display)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create program state
    state = types.SimpleNamespace()
    state.starttime = None
    state.run = False
    # Create widgets.
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Stopwatch")
    root.attributes('-type', 'dialog')
    # box to display stopwatch
    box = tk.Entry(root, width=20, borderwidth=5)
    box.grid(row=0, column=0)
    start_button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start)
    stop_button = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", command=stop)
    start_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
    stop_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
    # Run the GUI
    root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**

If you are new to Python it might be sensible to start with scripts that you can simply call from the command-line (`cmd.exe` on ms-windows). Those are generally much easier to read and write because they have a mostly linear control flow. On my website I have an [article](https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/programming/command-line-versus-gui-program.html) about two equivalant programs, one a simple command-line script and the other a `tkinter` GUI. You can see there that the latter is much more involved than the former.

Comment: Wow, goes to show that I've barely scratched the surface of Python. For context, this is the second thing I've tried to write longer than a few lines (the first being a GUI calculator that mostly works as intended and could probably be simplified). I'm very grateful for the time you've taken to respond in such detail - I have a lot to research before I can fully understand it.